# Are multiple accesses in a row to the same class member optimized in some way?

Tags: c++, optimization

In this piece of code, I access exitButton.rectangle several times consecutively, and I wondered if it's optimized so the object code produced doesn't have to ask `exitButton` for `rectangle` everytime:

```
struct MenuItem {
    Rectangle rectangle;
};

MenuItem exitButton;

exitButton.rectangle.top = 383;
exitButton.rectangle.height = 178;
exitButton.rectangle.left = 0;
exitButton.rectangle.width = 1024;
```

Do I need to write something like this instead to guarantee it is optimized?

```
Rectangle &tempRectangle = exitButton.rectangle;

tempRectangle.top = 383;
tempRectangle.height = 178;
tempRectangle.left = 0;
tempRectangle.width = 1024;
```

Would it be the same but using a class instead a struct? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

g++ -o0, no reference:

```
    CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
004013B0  /$  55            PUSH EBP                                 ; CppTest.004013B0(guessed void)
004013B1  |.  89E5          MOV EBP,ESP
004013B3  |.  83E4 F0       AND ESP,FFFFFFF0                         ; DQWORD (16.-byte) stack alignment
004013B6  |.  83EC 10       SUB ESP,10
004013B9  |.  E8 42060000   CALL 00401A00                            ; [CppTest.00401A00
004013BE  |.  C70424 7F0100 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.4],17F
004013C5  |.  C74424 04 B20 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.3],0B2
004013CD  |.  C74424 08 000 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.2],0
004013D5  |.  C74424 0C 000 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1],400
004013DD  |.  B8 00000000   MOV EAX,0
004013E2  |.  C9            LEAVE
004013E3  \.  C3            RETN
```

g++ -o0, reference:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
004013B0  /$  55            PUSH EBP                                 ; CppTest.004013B0(guessed void)
004013B1  |.  89E5          MOV EBP,ESP
004013B3  |.  83E4 F0       AND ESP,FFFFFFF0                         ; DQWORD (16.-byte) stack alignment
004013B6  |.  83EC 20       SUB ESP,20
004013B9  |.  E8 62060000   CALL 00401A20                            ; [CppTest.00401A20
004013BE  |.  8D4424 0C     LEA EAX,[LOCAL.5]
004013C2  |.  894424 1C     MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1],EAX
004013C6  |.  8B4424 1C     MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1]
004013CA  |.  C700 7F010000 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX],17F
004013D0  |.  8B4424 1C     MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1]
004013D4  |.  C740 04 B2000 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4],0B2
004013DB  |.  8B4424 1C     MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1]
004013DF  |.  C740 08 00000 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+8],0
004013E6  |.  8B4424 1C     MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1]
004013EA  |.  C740 0C 00040 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+0C],400
004013F1  |.  B8 00000000   MOV EAX,0
004013F6  |.  C9            LEAVE
004013F7  \.  C3            RETN
```

Comment: Using `-o0` is not that interesting, as it asks the compiler *not* to optimize the code.

Comment: I did the same test but using -o3, and I saved the results too. I can post it if you want, but you will quickly realize why I didn't post them in the first place.

-o3 optimizes away the assignments because they are not used!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case there actually isn't any optimization for the compiler to perform.  In fact, the compiler may actually have to work harder in the second case to produce equally efficient code; because for that it will have to resolve reference aliases.

The reason is because the `Rectangle` is not a pointer, but rather has been directly embedded into the `MenuItem`.  In such a case, the compiler actually sees the whole structure tree as a flat set of variables.  The compiler thinks of things in terms of *bytes offset from the start of the struct*.  Example:

```
struct Item1 {
    int i1, i2, i3;
};
struct Item2 {
    Item1  item1;
    int    t1, t2;
};
```

... is structurally equivalent internally to:

```
struct ItemAll {
    int i1, i2, i3;
    int t1, t2;
};
```

You could actually use a static cast between `Item2` and `ItemAll` in this example.  In either case, if you reference either `ItemAll.i2` or `Item2::Item1.i2` the compiler views it internally as `variable_base_address + sizeof(int)`.  **The same applies to classes as well as structs.**

What you need to be concerned about is when you're using the `-> operator`, eg if your struct was designed like so:

```
struct MenuItem {
    Rectangle* rectangle;
};
```

In this case, the compiler must do an extra dereferencing step to access contents of `Rectangle`.  With optimizations enabled, any modern compiler will optimize the dereferences as best it can.  That's not a problem.  Where a problem can occur is if you have a lot of interleaving dereferences that simply exceed available registers on the cpu:

```
struct MenuItem {
    Rectangle* rect1;
    Rectangle* rect2;
    Point*     point1;
    Point*     point2;
};

menuItem.rect1->top = 50;
menuItem.rect2->top = 50;
menuItem.point1->x  = 33;
menuItem.point2->x  = 45;

menuItem.rect1->bottom = 450;
menuItem.rect2->bottom = 450;
// etc...
```

In the above case the compiler may run out of registers suitable for use as base registers, forcing it to redundantly re-calculate the dereference for later uses (it won't run out of registers in this specific example since these are assigning immediates, but if any variable arithmetic were involved the chance becomes much higher).  Obviously in this case also it would be trivial for you to reorder things so that all rect1 assignments are paired, etc.  Though again, if we were doing something more complex than simple assignment then that might not be possible either.

In this case however, even using references won't help.  The compiler will have to spill and re-load the pointer dereferences in the same fashion regardless.

Conclusion: Feel free to use `Rectangle& var = menuItem.var;` as a code simplification tool.  It can make your code easier to maintain and reduce some of your typing!  But it won't help the compiler do its job, so if that's your aim, don't bother.

Comment: Abuse of class names as if they were instances.  But the explanation is correct.  +1

Comment: Thanks a lot, very deep explanation, it motivated me to look at the object code, as before I thought that C++ in assembler would look unreadable, and I became surprised about how it's not, at least in this small example.

Comment: Yeah, and the disasm snippet you pasted in your question illustrates how the reference version actually makes more work for the compiler.  In -O2 both versions should look very similar or identical, once the optimizer has done its duty.  But without any optimization passes, the compiler is unaware that the reference is an alias for the structure.

Comment: Also, on modern out-of-order-capable CPUs a few extra pointer dereferences are usually very cheap or entirely free. It only becomes a concern if you've got quite a lot of dereference juggling, or if you're targeting CPUs without out-of-order abilities (pretty much just ARM32-based mobile devices these days). Also, virtual functions in classes can add an additional level of dereferencing, which can compound the amount of dereferences being thrown around if those classes are also referenced by pointer. Any one thing by itself is insignificant, but compounded they can become unexpectedly heavy.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the second question first, class vs. struct will make no difference (at least with any sane compiler). The only difference between the two is the default accessibility of members (private for a class, public for a struct).

About the only way to be *sure* about optimization is to look at the object code, but I'd *expect* any reasonable compiler to determine that you're using the same series of references to get to `exitButton.rectangle` repeatedly, and automatically use a register to refer to that for the successive accesses.

If you turn off *all* optimization, that might not be the case, but with essentially any optimization allowed at all, you can expect it -- this optimization has been well known for years (it's basically a common subexpression elimination).

Comment: The subexpression `exitButton.rectangle` does not necessarily mean there's any kind of reading of that member going on, so having that subexpression repeated does not indicate that there's any kind of redundant reads that need to be optimized away. In this case even without any kind of optimization that series of assignments will end up simply being a series of stores.

Comment: @bames53: It's not about optimizing out redundant reads. It's about optimizing out the redundant additions to get to the correct offset. For most practical purposes, you can think of `exitButton.rectangle.A`, `exitButton.rectangle.B`, etc., as offsets from the base address of `exitButton` -- and rather than adding (for example) three offsets at run time, it can factor it to adding only one for each individual member.

Comment: Thanks, this answer gave me the main idea in a few lines.

Comment: Okay, I guess I don't see that as optimization, it's simply doing normal constant folding since the offsets are compile-time values. I have confirmed that using the `-O0` flag does not result in any extra runtime summation (and in fact the generated code is identical). It also does not look like common subexpression elimination to me.